# Orthogonality of zero vector relative to non-zero vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I was revising the topic of Dot Product in Stewart's Early Transcendentals textbook and I came across something that I need further clarification on.

As seen in the screenshot below, he says "The zero vector is considered to be perpendicular to all vectors." Now this follows the statement that if the dot product is 0, then cos θ = 0.

However, if we take the dot product of a non-zero vector and the zero vector, we can't get cos θ = 0 as the norms of the 2 vectors multiplied together is 0, and since the norms are in the denominator when we try to find θ, the fraction is undefined.

Therefore, how and why do we draw the conclusion that the zero vector is considered to be perpendicular to all vectors?

[image]

Comment: "*By definition*"

Comment: Two vectors are defined to be orthogonal if their scalar product is zero. Clearly this can happen either if one of the two has norm zero, or if $\cos(\theta)=0$. Usually you just think about the second because the fist occurs only for zero vectors. But the actual definition of orthogonality involves the scalar product, not the angle...

Comment: Could you edit paragraph 3 for grammar and readability please?

Comment: @ryang done! Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As seen in the screenshot below, he says "The zero vector is considered to be perpendicular to all vectors." Now this follows the statement that if the dot product is 0, then cos θ = 0.

No, you are over-reading: this statement is not being claimed to follow (be derived from) the previous sentence(s). The author is merely telling you that $\mathbf0$ is defined as perpendicular to every vector. (Side note: $\mathbf0$ is also defined as parallel to every vector.)

> [image]

This is how to read the excerpt: the final line, which is boxed up, is being introduced as a ***definition*** that is motivated by the discussion preceding it. While that discussion separately considers two cases (neither $\mathbf a$ nor $\mathbf b$ are zero vs. at least one of them is zero), the definition converges the two cases, so applies to all the possibilities for $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b.$ (Thus, the word '**orthogonal**' in Definition 7 ought to have been boldfaced, just like the two boldfaced words in the first line.)

> However, if we take the dot product of a non-zero vector and the zero vector, we can't get cos θ = 0 as as the norms of the 2 vectors multiplied together is 0, and since the norms are in the denominator when we try to find is θ, the fraction is undefined.

I can only guess what you're trying to say, which sounds like this: in the equation $$0=0\times p,$$ $p$ cannot be zero and $p$ in fact equals $\frac00.$

Comment: That really helped. Thank you, you guessed correctly. I had trouble trying to articulate what I was thinking. I never knew 0/0 could equal a variable.

Comment: No, you misunderstand, haha: my last sentence is merely emulating what I guess you are saying; it is of course nonsensical: when $p$ equals $0,$ both the LHS and RHS equal $0,$ so there is no problem!

Comment: Oh yes. I get it now. Thank you!